# aws-cdk kms multi-region key. What constructors use to setup regions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Using AWS CDK we could create multi-region KMS keys by

- Creating the principal key(pk) with the level 1 constructor [CfnKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_kms/CfnKey.html)
- Creating the replica of the principal key  using the level 1 constructor [CfnReplicaKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_kms/CfnReplicaKey.html), which takes as one of its parameters the pk_arn

Those constructors however do not specify the regions, where I want to make those keys available.

My question is:

*What aws-CDK constructor or pattern should I use to make the replicas available in certain regions, using aws-CDK?*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CfnReplicaKey` will be created in the parent stack's region (see a [CloudFormation example in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kms-replicakey.html#aws-resource-kms-replicakey--examples)).

For the CDK (and CloudFormation), the unit of deployment is [*Edit*:] the Stack, which is tied to one [environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/environments.html):

> Each Stack instance in your AWS CDK app is explicitly or implicitly associated with an environment (env). An environment is the target AWS account and region into which the stack is intended to be deployed.

This logic applies generally to all CDK resources - the account/region is defined at the **stack** level, not the construct level.  Stacks can be replicated across regions and accounts in several ways, including directly in a CDK app:

```py
# replicate the stack in several regions using CDK

app = core.App()

for region in ["us-east-1". "us-west-1", "us-central-1", "eu-west-1"]:
  MyStack(app, "MyStack_" + region, env=Environment(
        region=region,
        account="555599931100"
    ))
```

Comment: Your approach appears correct. I just wanted to clarify that as per AWS CDK the unit of deployment is indeed the Stack, as stated here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/stacks.html

Comment: That's not quite correct, the relationship is not 1:1 - you can have multiple Stacks per environment.